# System.AppDomainUnloadedException after close a VSTO application

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, vsto

I created an Addins VSTO for Excel with a WPF Window. Everything works fine. Unfortunatelly when I attached a WindowChrome window style, after closing an Excel an System.AppDomainUnloadedException error appears.

I have an Excel 2016, Visual Studio 2017, Net Framework 4.6.1.

This is acode of the Window1:

```
<Window x:Class="ExcelAddIn1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Shell"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExcelAddIn1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Title="Title" Width="300" Height="300" WindowState="{Binding CurWindowState, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:Window1}">
            <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <shell:WindowChrome
                        CaptionHeight="36"
                        GlassFrameThickness="-1"
                        ResizeBorderThickness="4" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Window1}">
                        <Grid>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid />
</Window>
```

This is a code behind of the Window1:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logika interakcji dla klasy Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += Window_Loaded;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Style _style = null;
            if (Microsoft.Windows.Shell.SystemParameters2.Current.IsGlassEnabled == true)
            {
                _style = (Style)Resources["GStyle"];
            }
            this.Style = _style;
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of a code of the AddIns:

```
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            (new Window1()).Show();
        }
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Usually this happens when you add an object to another object by registering for an event.  If you for example add the WPF to receive a notification from something in the VSTO or vice versa, then it's possible when the WPF code tries to call back into the VSTO listener or vice versa, the object has already been disposed (when you closed excel).  In short, it's best to remember to unregister for any events you register for.

Comment: Did you post all your code, or are you leaving stuff out?  Also, why do you not create a reference in your Add-in for your WPF form (ie. Window1 myWindow;)